# Create a desktop application using Electron api for existing Angular project

Tags: angularjs, api, electron, atom-editor

I have created a web based project in AngualrJs using Rest Api and now I want to create a desktop application using atom electron api, is there any way to create a desktop application in same with existing web based project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but you'll have to work a little, it don't have a magic project for this.

So if your webapp is not responsive, it's a problem.

And also read this : http://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron